# SQL Server Transactional Replication Missing articles

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

I am experimenting with Transactional Replication in SQL Server 2014 Standard edition.

Replication has been  setup and is mostly working with the exception of some views and functions that are missing at the subscriber after the initial snapshot. The Replication Monitor does not give me any errors.

What am I missing? what can cause some views and function to be left out while they are marked as articles in the publication?

Comment: I have never seen or heard of this before. Have you double checked that the missing views and functions where included in the snapshot?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the view(s) or function(s) are being replicated with a new owner selected, which would be odd, however, you would not have access to theses articles if you did not have proper access permission.

Comment: It gets stranger. Removed the publication and created it again now not selecting all functions but only a few. Among them a few that were not replicated in my first attempt and to my surprise they are now available. and there was one missing that was not missing before.

Comment: Are the objects that you're expecting to go across in the sysschemaarticles table at the publisher? If so, what does the schema_option column say for them? Do they show up in the snapshot files?